# "BULK COLLECT" in Oracle runs into an infinite loop

Tags: oracle, procedure, bulk, collect

I created the Package/Body as below in the SCOTT in Oracle.

```
-- PACKAGE SPECIFICATION:

create or replace package emp_pkg Is

    TYPE tbl_emp IS TABLE OF EMP%ROWTYPE;

    PROCEDURE p_displayEmpName;
   
end emp_pkg;
```

```
-- PACKAGE BODY:

create or replace package body emp_pkg Is
   
PROCEDURE p_displayEmpName IS   
    CURSOR c_rec IS select * from emp where deptno = 30;
    v_tbl_emp tbl_emp;
    BEGIN
        open c_rec;
        loop
            fetch c_rec bulk collect into v_tbl_emp;
            for i in 1..v_tbl_emp.count loop
                dbms_output.put_line(v_tbl_emp(i).ename || ','||v_tbl_emp(i).hiredate);
            end loop;
        end loop;
    END p_displayEmpName;
end emp_pkg;
```

I have no problems compiling the package and body.

Once I executed the procedure, it runs into an infinite loop:

```
-- CALL ing the procedure:
exec emp_pkg.p_displayempname;
```

How can I figure out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXIT` the loop when there are no more rows and `CLOSE` your cursor (yes, it should be implicitly closed but its better to get into good habits and always close it for when you work with a language/driver where the cursors aren't implicitly closed):

```sql
create or replace package body emp_pkg Is
   
PROCEDURE p_displayEmpName
IS   
  CURSOR c_rec IS select * from emp where deptno = 30;
  v_tbl_emp tbl_emp;
  BEGIN
    open c_rec;
    loop
      EXIT WHEN c_rec%NOTFOUND;
      fetch c_rec bulk collect into v_tbl_emp LIMIT 50;

      for i in 1..v_tbl_emp.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_tbl_emp(i).ename || ',' || v_tbl_emp(i).hiredate);
      end loop;
    end loop;

    CLOSE c_rec;
  END p_displayEmpName;
end emp_pkg;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c672c030b488ac3c93010ad88ae9b565)*